# Processing - Set X/Y Zero Coordinates To Center of Display Window

Tags: math, processing, processing.js

I'm trying to use latitude and longitude coordinates to plot a map in Processing. Is there a way to set the zero coordinates of the X and Y axis to the center of the display window.

Or does anyone know how to convert spherical coordinates to cartesian?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a 2D map, yes, `translate(width*.5,height*.5);` at the start of your `draw()` loop is the easiest option. Tom's formula is converting [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) to cartezian(x,y,z) which is handy if you want to plot lat lon coordinates on a 3D sphere.

Comment: @George Profenza Ah thanks, that makes more sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you have spherical coordinates of r, radius; theta, horizontal angle around Z-axis starting at (1,0,0) and rotating toward (0,1,0); and phi, vertical angle from positive Z-axis toward negative Z-axis; that being how I remember it from back when. Remember that angles are in radians in most programming languages; 2*pi radians = 180 degrees.

```
x = r * cos(theta) * sin(phi)
y = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi)
z = r * cos(phi)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'd love to understand this but my maths is a bit weak at the moment. I found a solution with the translate() method.